# Cross-domain jQuery ajax not working in firefox

Tags: firefox, jquery, cross-domain

Because of my free host's limitations, I need to call a cross-server request from a friends host where I uploaded a simple script.

I've set the headers in the script on my friends domain to allow cross server calls from my own host.
It works in google Chrome and Safari but doesn't work in FireFox (and IE).
Here is the particular line:

```
$.post("http://someothersite.com", {action : 'generate', usr: un}, function(url){
                    $("#thelink").html(url);
    });
});
```

What am I overlooking? I've looked practically everywhere all day long trying to grasp what is going wrong. Obviously I am a noob, but just trying to learn here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156620/jquery-ajax-form-cross-domain-firefox-issues

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Are you trying to say with that link that whatever I'm doing it is just not possible in firefox?

Comment: What you're trying to do is quite possible, if you're sending the right CORS headers.  What headers is the someothersite.com page sending?

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Head... X-PINGOTHER
Access-Control-Allow-Meth... POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Orig... http://someothersite.com/
Access-Control-Max-Age 1728000
Cache-Control no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding gzip
Content-Length 46
Content-Type text/html
Date Tue, 17 Jan 2012 09:06:49 GMT
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive timeout=1, max=1000
Pragma no-cache
Server Apache/2
Set-Cookie PHPSESSID=69c083d9a86f540ab63cde5195f1faf2; path=/
Vary Accept-Encoding,User-Agent

Comment: I hope I understood you correctly, above is the header output from firebug. Thanks for commenting and helping!